# pandas interpolation : use np.interp with changing values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have a 3 million rows dataframe that contains the different values :

```
d    a0    a1    a2
0.5    10.0    5.0    1.0
0.8    10.0    2.0    0.0
```

I want to fill a fourth column with a linear interpolation of (a0,a1,a2) that takes the value in the "d" case,

```
d    a0    a1    a2    newcol
1.5    10.0    5.0    1.0    3.0
0.8    10.0    2.0    0.0    3.6
```

newcol is the weighted average between a[int(d)] and a[int(d+1)], e.g. when d = 0.8,  newcol = 0.2 * a0 + 0.8 * a1    because 0.8 is 80% of the way between 0 and 1

I found that np.interp can be used, but there is no way for me to put the three column names in variable) :

```
df["newcol"]=np.interp(df["d"],[0,1,2], [100,200,300])
```

will indeed give me

```
d    a0    a1    a2    newcol
1.5    10.0    5.0    1.0    250.0
0.8    10.0    2.0    0.0    180.0
```

BUT I have no way to specify that the values vector changes :

```
df["newcol"]=np.interp(df["d"],[0,1,2], df[["a0","a1","a2"]])
```

gives me the following traceback :

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 1271, in interp
>   return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
>   ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Is there any way to use a different vector for values at each line?  Could you think of any workaround ?

Basically, I could find no way to create this new column based on the definition :

> What is the value in x = column "d" of the function that is piecewise linear 
>   between given points and whose values at these points are described in the columns "ai"

Edit:  Before, I used scipy.interp1d, which is not memory efficient, the comment helped me to solve partially my problem

Edit2 :

I tried the approach from ev-br that stated that I had to try to code the loop myself.

```
for i in range(len(tps)):
    columns=["a1","a2","a3"]
    length=len(columns)
    x=np.maximum(0,np.minimum(df.ix[i,"d"],len-2))
    xint = np.int(x)
    xfrac = x-xint
    name1=columns[xint]
    name2=columns[xint+1]
    tps.ix[i,"Multiplier"]=df.ix[i,name1]+xfrac*(df.ix[i,name2]-tps.ix[i,name1])
```

The above loop loops around 50 times a second, so I guess I have a major optimisation issue. What part of working on a DataFrame do I do wrong?

Comment: if you only need linear interpolation, `numpy.interp` might be saner.

Comment: Alternatively, you could calculate the weighed average inside the apply function, exactly in the way you show.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I now use np.interp, I'm closer to my answer, so I modified my question accordingly (it is now clearer)

Comment: Now that you're changing the question, I lose interest in cooking up a detailed reply, but basically: write yourself a solution using a for loop over the rows of your dataframe, then drop it to cython and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

It might comes a bit too late, but I would use np.interpolate with pandas' apply function. Creating the DataFrame in your example:

```
t = pd.DataFrame([[1.5,10,5,1],[0.8,10,2,0]], columns=['d', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2'])
```

Then comes the apply function:

```
t.apply(lambda x: np.interp(x.d, [0,1,2], x['a0':]), axis=1)
```

which yields:

```
0    3.0
1    3.6
dtype: float64
```

This is perfectly usable on "normal" datasets. However, the size of your DataFrame might call for a better/more optimized solution. The processing time scales linearily, my machine clocks in 10000 lines per second, which means 5 minutes for 3 million...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a second solution, which uses the numexpr module. This method is much more specific, but also much faster. I've measured the complete process to take 733 milliseconds for 1 million lines, which is not bad...

So we have the original DataFrame as before:

```
t = pd.DataFrame([[1.5,10,5,1],[0.8,10,2,0]], columns=['d', 'a0', 'a1', 'a2'])
```

We import the module and use it, but it requires that we separate the two cases where we will use 'a0' and 'a1' or 'a1' and 'a2' as lower/upper limits for the linear interpolation. We also prepare the numbers so they can be fed to the same evaluation (hence the -1). We do that by creating 3 arrays with the interpolation value (originally: 'd') and the limits, depending on the value of "d". So we have:

```
import numexpr as ne

lim = np.where(t.d > 1, [t.d-1, t.a1, t.a2], [t.d, t.a0, t.a1])
```

Then we evaluate the simple linear interpolation expression and finally add it as a new column like that:

```
x = ne.evaluate('(1-x)*a+x*b', local_dict={'x': lim[0], 'a': lim[1], 'b': lim[2]})
t['IP'] = np.where(t.d > 1, x+1, x)
```